# Restoring data while upgrading database in android

Tags: android

I have developed an app and I have a database.
When I upgrade the database with new columns, I lose the data in it.
I created two tables, now what if I want to add new columns? Should I alter the table or should I drop and recreate it? If I just alter the table will I lose the data?

Here is the database class:

```
public class data extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String dbName="furniture_info.db";
    static String logintable="login";
    static String rowid="log_masterid";
    static String UID="email_id";
    static String passw="password";
    static String flag="active_flag";
    static String cName="username";
    static String Age="age";
    static String colDept="dept";
    static String sid="std_id";
    static String stinfo="stdinfo";
    static String sname="name";
    static String phone="phno";
    static String city="user_city";
    static String state="user_state";
    static String pincode="user_pincode";
    static String user_id="user_id";
    static String user_info="user_info";



     public data(Context con) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(con,dbName,null,11);
     }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {

            boolean a=checkDataBase();
            if(a==false)
            {
                String stmt="CREATE TABLE "+logintable+" ("+rowid+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                        +UID+ " TEXT, "+ passw + " TEXT, "+ cName +" TEXT, "+ phone +" INTEGER, "+flag+" INTEGER "+")";
            //String stmt="CREATE TABLE "+colltable+" ("+colID+ " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"+")";
                db.execSQL(stmt);
                String stm="CREATE TABLE user_info (" + user_id +" INTEGER, "+ city +" TEXT, "+ state +" TEXT, "+ pincode + " INTEGER , foreign key ("+ user_id +") references "+ logintable+"("+ rowid +") )";
                db.execSQL(stm);
            }
            //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ stinfo +" ("+sname+ " TEXT, " +Age+ " TEXT, "+ phone +" TEXT " +sid+" INTEGER NOT NULL ,FOREIGN KEY ("+sid+") REFERENCES  "+colltable+" ("+sid+"));");
//          Toast.makeText(null, "table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldv,int newv)
        {


                //final String ALTER_TBL = "ALTER TABLE " + logintable +" ADD COLUMN"+ passw+" text,"+flag+"INTEGER;";

            // deleteDatabase(dbName);
             //Toast.makeText(null, "database deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //File dbFile =new File(getDatabasePath(dbName));
            //db.deleteDatabase(dbFile);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + logintable);    
            onCreate(db);
}
        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("//data/data/com.furniture/databases/furniture_info.db", null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
                checkDB.close();
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                // database doesn't exist yet.
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }
```

I know that it upgrades when I increment the version number of the DB, but the problem is that I am losing the data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are losing the data because in `onUpgrade(...)` you are deleting the table and then recreating it from scratch. If you want to alter the table without deleting it, you can use the `ALTER TABLE` SQL command. It looks like you already had that in place at one point, but commented it out for some reason.

Comment: thanx ll try tht out mate:)

Answer (score 0):

Altering a table does not affect any data already in it. Increment your database version, compare the old and new version numbers in onUpgrade and execute the alter SQL (or any other SQL you need to apply) accordingly. By comparing what the old version is and what the new one is, you can work out what updates need to be made to bring the existing database up to the current schema definition.

One thing to watch out for with ALTER is if you add a column with the constraint NOT NULL. That will fail if there are existing rows in the table but that can be worked around. However I can't see any issues like that in this case.